# How to Log an error in IIS error Log?

Tags: asp.net

I just wanted to dump all my errors into the IIS servers error log.

I am using Asp.net in order to write web services.

so is it possible? if yes then could anyone please help me.

Best Regards,
~Anup

Comment: Do you mean the event log for IIS or the IIS log files?

Comment: yes I mean to say add my error text to IIS log file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/313437

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how should I programmatically add the error text to Log file.

Comment: I think for your own error messages you'll have to use a separate log. IIS may not allow you to put your own messages in its logs. Custom error logging can be as simple as dumping these messages in a text file to using logging frameworks such as Log4Net. What kind of logging do you want to implement?

Comment: I have already implemented my own error logger, but what happened if my error log fails, then there is no way to know what is the error.

Comment: Why would your error log fail? IIS logs basically tells you about what happened with each request. Whether it got served correctly or not, how much data was sent by the client to server and vice versa etc. But the kind of information that you'll get in IIS logs would be rather peripheral so you need to find out why your logging is not working.